Query MongoCollection for data between two Date Strings
Im trying to create a query to search for all collections that are in between of two Date strings, however all my attempts have failed and every time I try a query it always return no results
this is the query im using:
const intialDate = new Date('2024-05-23T06:00:00.000Z');
const endDate = new Date('2024-05-24T20:44:02.172Z');

const dispoquery = this.guestModel.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or:[
        {
          initial: {
          $gte: intialDate
          }
        },
        {
          end: {
          $lte: endDate
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}).catch((err) => {
  return err;
})
.then((doc:any)=> {
      return doc
      })

I need all documents that comply this assortment:
intial >= intialDate || end <= endDate 

But I always get no results
this is a sample data of my collection:
{
  "folio": "W1013",
  "nombre": "CArlos",
  "initial": "2024-05-23T06:00:00.000Z",
  "end": "2024-05-24T19:52:11.050Z",
  "__v": 0
}

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong please?

The field names in your query do not match the field names in the data element you show.

shouldnt you be using just $and to get records between 2 days https://mongoplayground.net/p/6pmHZrDY6Vd. 2. your example data has differet field names? 3. are you saving dates as string in mongo side, if so can you try without the new Date part

You should never store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store proper Date objects, then your query will work and you avoid many other issues.

Some issues with your data and query:

Your query has the words initial & end but your DB document has llegada & salida.

Your documents have the dates as Strings, not as Date Objects. And you are comparing with Date objects, not Strings.

So either do it as a String comparison (not recommended) or convert your llegada & salida to dates using $dateFromString.
If you will always use only UTC for all date variables and all your documents have date strings which represent UTC then you can do it as a String comparison
But if there may be multiple timezones used, then convert them with $dateFromString during the query


There's no need to use $and if it's just one $or clause within it.

As cmgchess commented, if you are looking for something between two dates, you should only use $and, not $or.
But your question says

intial >= intialDate || end <= endDate 


So I'll keep the logic the same as per what you already have. But you should probably do
intial >= intialDate && end <= endDate 



Since some conversions need to be done on the document data while querying, you'll need to use $expr with your comparisons/checks.
db.guestModel.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $gte: [
          { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$llegada" } },
          intialDate
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$salida" } },
          endDate
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})

Mongo Playground

Thanks for the explanation, it worked as expected! does $expr need to be use to be able to do $dateFromString?

Im getting a weird behavior, no matter which date I pass to the query it always returns the document even if its not on the range, I have tested some dates for $llegada and $salida and it always returns the document

got it working now by replacing the $or with $and

1. Wrt "does $expr need to be use to be able to do $dateFromString?" When doing a simple field: {$gte: some_value} it's not needed but to use $dateFromString, we can't do {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$field" } }: {$gte: some_value}. Also, in order to access the field from the document and use "aggregation expressions" like $dateFromString, we have to use $expr. 2. Yup, the $or vs $and usage raised some concerns the question's comments, which I've addressed in # 4.
